# DateTime format is out of format

Tags: apex, visualforce

i have a field of DateTime data type in an object. I have called it in a VF page. In VF page Standard stylesheets is set to FALSE. Still i'm getting a standard date/time format when i put the mouse over the Date/Time field at VF page

Can anyone why its happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`standardStylesheets = "false"` would only make changes to the CSS applied to the Salesforce page, to make changes to the date/time formats, refer to the example below:

```
<apex:outputText value="The formatted time right now is:  {0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}"> 
                 //0 - corresponds to the n-th nested param tag below
                 //date - datatype
                 //MM'/'dd'/'yyyy - format. The single quotes escapes the slashes.
         <apex:param value="{!TODAY()}" /> //Your date field in here.
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: Saket Joshi, My requirement is to show in inputtext/inputField formats. ur method doesn't fit for my requirement. However, thank you pal..

Comment: You never mentioned inputFields, anyways, if you are using input fields for date/time, they will always show the format as per the user's context
In order to change the format, you would require custom datepickers like that of jQuery UI

Comment: Sorry!!  I have added custom datepicker js files. Here the main problem is why the standard layout of date/time field is getting displayed eventhough we have disable the standard style sheets

Comment: As I already told you, standardStylesheets disables the Salesforce standard stylesheets, meaning the default salesforce CSS stylings would not be applied. This has nothing to do with date/time formats, the formats are decided based on the current user's settings. You can change the locale for your user and see for yourself

Comment: Saket.. it seems u didn't get my point.. the datepicker which should come if standard style sheets is false is appearing still in my VF page..